How to get logs each EBS snapshot done by EBS lifecycle manager in AWS
If anyone has experience in AWS, I need a little help on the below:
How to get logs each EBS snapshot done by EBS lifecycle manager in AWS?
Is it done by cloudtrail or cloudwatch?!!
and how I can do that?!!
Thanks in advance

you can find the metrics from cloudwatch. please refer below link.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ebs/latest/userguide/monitor-dlm-cw-metrics.html
